# How can I use properly the Selection method with gameObjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For context: I have this script called InputText put in a controller that is attach to 6 InputField (TMP) on the function On End Edit (String)

[image]

The thing is that when one of the InputFields is written in, I want to interactuate with this script and give me on which InputField has the user put something (because each InputField is kept in a specific canvas and each canvas in an object)

[image]

I tried this function called Selection and it worked for sometime but then it didn't for some reason.... Is there something I did wrong? Is there even a better solution?

```
public void ReadStringInput(string userInput)
    {
        string input = userInput;
        Debug.Log(input);

        GameObject selectedObject = Selection.activeGameObject; //CONSEGUIMOS EL INPUTFIELD
        GameObject canvasObject = selectedObject.GetComponentInParent<Canvas>().gameObject; //CONSEGUIMOS EL CANVAS
        GameObject casilla = canvasObject.transform.parent.gameObject; //CONSEGUIMOS LA CASILLA --> LO QUE INTERESA

        ComprobarCodigo(casilla);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Selection](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Selection.html) class only works in the editor.
Anything defined in the `UnityEditor` namespace is available only while in the editor.

At runtime you can go through the [EventSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html) to get the currently selected game object.

> public GameObject [currentSelectedGameObject;](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem-currentSelectedGameObject.html)
>
> The GameObject currently considered active by the EventSystem.

```
var selected = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of linking this via the hierarchy you could instead have a component and set the callbacks up via script. That way you can pass on additional references:

```
// in general I recommend you get used to code in english ;)
public class Controlador : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private TMP_InputField[] inputs;

    private void Start()
    {
        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            var canvas = input.GetComponentInParent<Canvas>();
            var casilla = canvas.transform.parent.gameObject;
            input.onEndEdit.AddListener(value => ReadStringInput(value, casilla));
        }
    }

    private void ReadStringInput(string userInput, GameObject casilla)
    {
        Debug.Log($"User input \"{userInput}\" on {casilla}", this);

        // ...
    }
}
```